# Parameterized stored procedure paginated return row count based on parameters excluding pagesize parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I would like to be able to get the row count for the query from my stored procedure, but not taking into account the pagesize limit with the pagination.

Here is my stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @OrderId INT = 0,
    @WarehouseId INT = 0,
    @PaymentMethodSystemName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @OrderStatusId INT = 0,
    @PaymentStatusId INT = 0,
    @ShippingStatusId INT = 0,
    @BillingEmail NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingFirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingLastName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ShippingMethod NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CreatedFromUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @PageIndex INT = 0, 
    @PageSize INT = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP (@PageSize) *
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT * 
         FROM [Test].[dbo].[Address] a 
         WHERE (@BillingEmail IS NULL OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
           AND (@BillingFirstName IS NULL OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
           AND (@BillingLastName IS NULL OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)) a 
         ON a.Id = o.BillingAddressId
         AND o.[Deleted] = 0
         AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)
         AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
         AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS NULL OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)
         AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
         AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
         AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)
         AND (@ShippingMethod IS NULL OR o.[ShippingMethod] = @ShippingMethod)
         AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
         AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
         AND o.[Id] >= @PageIndex
         AND o.[Id] < @PageSize
    ORDER BY 
        o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC 
        -- OFFSET @PageIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

    --total records
    SET @TotalRecords = @@rowcount
END
```

So this bit of code at the bottom `SET @TotalRecords = @@rowcount`, returns 50 which is my page size. I expect about 1500.

How would I go about returning the number of rows, as if no pagination parameters are passed which are `@PageIndex` and `@PageSize`.

I'm also going to mention that I thought about some kind of `count()` in the select statement, but I can't see a way to assign it to the parameter `@TotalRecords`.

```
SELECT TOP (@PageSize) *, COUNT(o.id) AS TotalRecords
```

> UPDATE
>   I have the pagination kind of working but it's not quite right. It's returning the total number of records from my order table, but it's like the parameters which insert into the `#TempTotal` table are being ignored. I think I made a mistake with it.

Here is the code:

```
create table #TempTotal (RowNum int identity(1,1), id int);
create index #IK_temp on #TempTotal (id);
-- Insert statements for procedure here
--select all
INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
    SELECT o.[Id]
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o with (NOLOCK)

left join 
    (select * from [Test].[dbo].[Address] a 
        where (@BillingEmail IS null OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
        AND (@BillingFirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
        AND (@BillingLastName IS null OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)) a
        ON a.Id = o.BillingAddressId

AND o.[Deleted] = 0
AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)
AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS NULL OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)
AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)
AND (@ShippingMethod IS NULL OR o.[ShippingMethod] = @ShippingMethod)
AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
ORDER BY o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC

-- Return the paged records
select TOP (@PageSize) *
from [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
where ord.Id in (
      select id
      from #TempTotal
      Where (ord.[Id] >= @PageIndex AND ord.[Id] < @PageSize)

)
ORDER BY ord.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;
```

> UPDATE 2
>   The answer from @DaleK works for pagination, but I had to join my address table like so.

```
LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Address] a on a.Id = o.BillingAddressId and (
        coalesce(@BillingEmail,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingFirstName,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingLastName,'') <> ''
    )
    WHERE (@BillingEmail IS null OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
    AND (@BillingFirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
    AND (@BillingLastName IS null OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)
```

Also bear in mind I also modified the returning of page records like so:

```
-- Return the paged records
    select TOP (@PageSize) *
    from [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
    where ord.Id in (
      select id
      from #TempTotal
      Where (ord.[Id] > @PageIndex)
```

> UPDATE 3
>   I also had to update the pagination to calculate the index, I my cms send pageindex as page1, 2, 3 and so on. Your situation may require something similar. Full code looks lie this :)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @OrderId INT = 0,
    @WarehouseId INT = 0,
    @PaymentMethodSystemName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @OrderStatusId INT = 0,
    @PaymentStatusId INT = 0,
    @ShippingStatusId INT = 0,
    @BillingEmail NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingFirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingLastName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ShippingMethod NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CreatedFromUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @PageIndex INT = 0, 
    @PageSize INT = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    create table #TempTotal (RowNum int identity(1,1), id int);
    create index #IK_temp on #TempTotal (RowNum);
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --select all
    INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
        SELECT o.[Id]
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o with (NOLOCK)

    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Address] a on a.Id = o.BillingAddressId and (
        coalesce(@BillingEmail,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingFirstName,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingLastName,'') <> ''
    )
    WHERE (@BillingEmail IS null OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
    AND (@BillingFirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
    AND (@BillingLastName IS null OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)

    AND o.[Deleted] = 0
         AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)
         AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
         AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS NULL OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)
         AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
         AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
         AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)
         AND (@ShippingMethod IS NULL OR o.[ShippingMethod] = @ShippingMethod)
         AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
         AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
ORDER BY o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;

--paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex

-- Return the paged records
    select TOP (@PageSize) *
    from [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
    where ord.[Id] in (
      select id
      from #TempTotal tt
      Where (tt.RowNum > @PageLowerBound)

    )ORDER BY ord.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;

    --total records
    select @TotalRecords = count(*) from #TempTotal; -- To get the total record count

    DROP TABLE #TempTotal
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Duplicate the query without the `TOP` just to get the `count(*)`
2. Use your query as it stands to get the id and insert that into a temp table which contains an `identity` column (`RowNum`) which you then use for paging then obtain the count before obtaining the actual records e.g.

```
    create table #temp (id int, RowNum int identity(1,1));
    create index #IK_temp on #temp (RowNum);

    -- insert your ids from your full query here

    -- Assign your total record count
    select @TotalRecords = count(*) from #temp; -- To get the total record count

    -- Return the paged records
    select *
    from MyTable
    where id in (
      select id
      from #temp
      order by RowNum asc
      offset (@PageStart-1) rows fetch next @Pagesize rows only
    );
```

Option 2 will perform significantly better because it reduces the amount of data that SQL Server has to deal with.

As an aside you should never `select *` as it leads to unexpected, and potentially badly performing behaviour. Always list your columns.

Comment: Hey Thanks @DaleK we are kind of getting there, except I'm getting way too many records back. Think I made a mistake with it.
Also I figure the last thing I should do in my stored procedure is drop that temp table ```DROP TABLE #TempTotal```

Comment: I'm leaving the office for the weekend, but something wierd is going on where I'm getting over 100,000 results back as totalrecords although only 35 records

Comment: I updated my question with the updated code, can you see where I might be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: @chrisc you've lost you `where` clause and created a giant `join` clause. My guess is `AND o.[Deleted] = 0` should be `WHERE o.[Deleted] = 0`.

Comment: Although the original query you posted had that issue as well. You should literally be able to take your old query (pre-paging), and only select id instead of multiple columns.

Comment: I thought I was only selecting the id here ```INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
    SELECT o.[Id]
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o with (NOLOCK)```

Comment: You are, I was just saying that as the rest of the query doesn't change I don't know how its stopped working properly. But do fix your where clause.

Comment: Ahh ok, I think I have an idea whats going on. If I comment out that left join section, it works like I would expect ```left join 
    (select * from [Test].[dbo].[Address] a ``` so there is something wrong with that left join, it's lkike that where clause never runs or something like that

Comment: You've made a giant join, I'm pretty sure `AND o.[Deleted] = 0` should be `WHERE o.[Deleted] = 0`

Comment: I updated my question with the left join which was required to get it working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also you might like to update your answer, I changed the select from #temp and added ```Where (RowNum > @PageStart)``` and used ```select TOP (@PageSize) *```. have added to my question

Comment: If you want to use `TOP` you have to make sure you also use the correct `order by`

Comment: I would also change your `select *` to a select specific columns. Not only will it perform better if you don't need all columns, but its clearer in general.

Comment: @chrisc updated again to use `offset ... fetch next` which is the recommended way to do it. (still produces the same results in the same time).

Comment: thanks for the heads up, if that's the recommended way to do it I will update my code, cheers :)

Comment: It does run quicker by using the recommended method ```offset (@PageStart-1) rows fetch next @Pagesize rows only```

Answer (score 0):

Try with CTE

```
SET @lFirstRec = ( @PageIndex – 1 ) * @PageSize 
         SET @lLastRec = ( @PageIndex * @PageSize + 1 )
         SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec – @lLastRec + 1

    ; WITH CTE_Results
             AS (
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.Id                       
           ) AS ROWNUM,
           Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
           * 
       from [Test].[dbo].[Address] a 
        where (@BillingEmail IS null OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
        AND (@BillingFirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
        AND (@BillingLastName IS null OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)) a
        ON a.Id = o.BillingAddressId

    AND
        o.[Deleted] = 0

    AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)

    AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)

    AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS null OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)

    AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
    AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)

    AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)

    AND (@ShippingMethod IS null OR o.[ShippingMethod] = @ShippingMethod)

    AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
    AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
    )
    SELECT
        TotalCount,
        ROWNUM,
        CPC.*
    FROM CTE_Results AS CPC
    WHERE
             ROWNUM > @lFirstRec
                   AND ROWNUM < @lLastRec
     ORDER BY CPC.CreatedOnUtc DESC, ROWNUM ASC
```

For more detail on approach refer:

https://pranavwithyou.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/stored-procedure-having-sorting-paging-and-filtering/